# Using a stack to calculate a molecular mass

Tags: java, stack, chemistry

I am tasked with using a stack of integers to calculate the molecular mass of a given molecule. I was supposed to implement the IntStack class myself using an array. I was then supposed to make a class that takes a String as an input and evaluate the molecule. The only characters in the input will be open and closed parentheses, numbers 2-9, and H (hydrogen), C (carbon) and O (oxygen). I was given the molecular masses of the three elements as 1, 12, and 16, respectively.

```
public class IntStack
{
private int[] stack;
public int index;

public IntStack()
{
    stack = new int[100];
    index = -1;
}

public void push(int x)
{
    stack[index + 1] = x;
    index++;
}

public int pop()
{
    if (index == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int num = stack[index];
    index--;
    return num;
}

public int peek()
{
    if (index == -1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return stack[index];
}
}


import java.util.Scanner;

public class MolecularMass
{
 private static IntStack stack;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
stack = new IntStack();
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the molecule: ");
String input = kb.nextLine();
int result = evaluate(input);
System.out.println("The Molecular Mass of " + input +  " is " + result);
}

public static int evaluate(String s)
{
int answer = 0;
int num = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
  char c = s.charAt(i);
  switch(c)
  {
    case '2':
      num = stack.pop();
      num *= 2;
      stack.push(num);
      break;
    case '3':
      num = stack.pop();
      num *= 3;
      stack.push(num);
      break;
    case '4':
      num = stack.pop();
      num *= 4;
      stack.push(num);
      break;
    case '5':
      num = stack.pop();
      num *= 5;
      stack.push(num);
      break;
    case '6':
      num = stack.pop();
      num *= 6;
      stack.push(num);
      break;
    case '7':
      num = stack.pop();
      num *= 7;
      stack.push(num);
      break;
    case '8':
      num = stack.pop();
      num *= 8;
      stack.push(num);
      break;
    case '9':
      num = stack.pop();
      num *= 9;
      stack.push(num);
      break;
    case 'C':
      stack.push(12);
      break;
    case 'H':
      stack.push(1);
      break;
    case 'O':
      stack.push(16);
      break;
    case '(':
      stack.push(0);
      break;
    case ')':
      int result = 0;
      while(stack.peek() != 0)
      {
        result += stack.pop();
      }
      int throwaway = stack.pop();
      stack.push(result);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

for(int i = 0; i < stack.index; i++)
{
  answer += stack.pop();
}

return answer;
}
}
```

It is supposed to run as follows:

Enter the molecule: ((CH)2(OH2H)(C(H))O)3

The Molecular Mass of ((CH)2(OH2H)(C(H))O)3 is 222

I keep getting the molecular mass as either 0 or 1

EDIT: Here's my algorithm for the evaluate method:
If the character is a chemical element, the program pushes the molecular weight of the element. 
If the character is an open parenthesis, the program pushes a 0 onto the stack.
If the character is a close parenthesis, the program adds up everything inside the parentheses until it gets to the open parenthesis (stored as 0)
If the character is a number, it pops the number on the stack, multiplies it by the input number, and pushes it back onto the stack
At the end, it adds up everything in the stack and returns the result.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the output I got

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: You should use `substring` and `indexOf` to do you calculation instead of switch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in the process of learning to code, I suggest that you follow a process for finding the error yourself. Here's how I suggest you approach it:

1. Write a set of unit tests to make sure your `IntStack` does exactly what you expect.
2. Move the `evaluate` logic into a separate class (that uses `IntStack` as a hidden implementation detail)
3. Provide several methods to perform the various parts of `evaluate` such as `element(Character)`, `count(Character)`, `startGroup()`, `endGroup()`.
4. As you create each of these methods, create unit tests that make sure they do exactly what you expect.
5. Once they are all working perfectly, write you code to read the input and call the various methods you've written.

This will take you longer than one of us pointing out your error but I guarantee you'll learn a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Or what you can do is use a String stack.

1. Iterate through the length of given string.If the character at ith index is '(' ,push it to the stack.
2. And then, when we see a ')', we define a variable to store the sum of the elements in between the opening and closing parenthesis.
3. We do this by popping the stack until we find '(' and by adding all those popped elements to the variable and then finally pushing that variable into the stack.
4. push 1 if you find a 'H' ,16 if you get an oxygen atom and 12 for carbon.
5. As soon as we see a number, we pop the top most element and multiply it with the number.
6. And at last after the loop gets over only the num remains in the stack which has to be added, add them up using a while loop. You can refer this code and if you want you can make you own String stack.

```java
    public class MassOfMolecules {
    
    private static int getValue(char c) {
        if (c == 'H')
            return 1;
        if (c == 'O')
            return 16;
        else
            return 12;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.next();
        int n = str.length();
        long ans = 0;
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        String checkM = "OCH";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if(c=='(') {
                stack.push("(");
            }
            else if(checkM.contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
                stack.push(String.valueOf(getValue(c)));
            }
            else if(c==')') {
                long x = 0;
                while(!stack.peek().contains("(")) {
                    x=x+Long.parseLong(stack.pop());
                }
                stack.pop();
                stack.push(String.valueOf(x));
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                long x = 0;
                if(!stack.isEmpty()) {
                    x = Long.parseLong(stack.pop())*Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(c));
                    stack.push(String.valueOf(x));
                }
            }
        }
        long x = 0;
        while(!stack.isEmpty()&&!stack.peek().contains("(")) {
            x = x + Long.parseLong(stack.pop());
        }
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    }
```